# Tap Gesture not Working for imageView in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 6 custom cells in the table view. In that 3 of them have an image view I added tapGesture to imageView and enabled the user interaction of imageView still not working. I also tried to add tapGesture in main tread in table view cell class but no use, I even tried to add gesture in the cell for at IndexPath method but not worked, how to solve this?

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellArr = sections[indexPath.section].cell
    //Loading cell based on array details
    switch cellArr[0] {
     case is InsuranceDetails:
         let insuranceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "insuranceCell") as! InsuranceCell
         insuranceCell.setup(object: cellArr[indexPath.row], in: tableView, at: indexPath)


    case is Pollution:
        let pollutionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pollutionCell") as! PollutionCell
        pollutionCell.setup(object: cellArr[indexPath.row], in: tableView, at: indexPath)
        return pollutionCell
    case is Servicing:
        let servicingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "servicingCell") as! ServicingCell
        servicingCell.setup(object: cellArr[indexPath.row], in: tableView, at: indexPath)
        return servicingCell
    case is ChallanPaid:
        let challanPaidCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "challanPaidCell") as! ChallanPaidCell
        challanPaidCell.setup(object: cellArr[indexPath.row], in: tableView, at: indexPath)
        return challanPaidCell
    case is InsuranceClaims:
       let insuranceClaimCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "insuranceClaimCell") as! InsuranceClaimCell
        insuranceClaimCell.setup(object: cellArr[indexPath.row], in: tableView, at: indexPath)
        return insuranceClaimCell
    case is FuelRefills:
         let fuelRefillCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fuelRefillCell") as! FuelRefillCell
        fuelRefillCell.setup(object: cellArr[indexPath.row], in: tableView, at: indexPath)
        return fuelRefillCell
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }



}
```

one of my tableview cell class

```
    class InsuranceCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var insurancePhoto: UIImageView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code


}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

    func setup(object: NSManagedObject, in table: UITableView, at indexPath: IndexPath) {


    guard let arr = object as? InsuranceDetails else {return}
    let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
    insurancePhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    insurancePhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    insurancePhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)

    // Do time consuming stuff in the background
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let imageData = arr.insurancePhoto ?? Data()
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        let compimage = image?.resized(withPercentage: 0.5)
        // Always back to the main thread/queue for UI updates
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let cell = table.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? InsuranceCell else {  return   }
            cell.insurancePhoto.image = compimage


        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: where did you write imageTapped method?

Comment: set selectionStyle = .none in the tableviewCell

Comment: I have writen the imageTapped func in this class only but I forgot to mention